# jQuery addClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass

I'm trying to make a custom simple toggle buttons with addClass and removeClass.

The buttons look like this:

```
<input type="button" class="btn shortcutson" value="Enable">
<input type="button" class="btn shortcutsoff selected" value="Disable">
```

and for the toggle I use this:

```
$(".searchbtnon").click(function(){
        $('.searchbtnoff').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
    $(".searchbtnoff").click(function(){
        $('.searchbtnon').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
```

Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class names do not match your HTML content.

Your `input`s say `shortcutson`

but your jQuery looks for `.searchbtnon`

Change them to match and you should be ok.

Comment: Really sorry. Got confused with the jsFiddle's. Can you vote for close please? Thanks

Comment: Done as requested @jQuerybeast...although you could also accept it ;-)